# Conversion of PDF to PNG or JPEG using Ghostscript, PHP5.10 & MacOSX (10.9.4)

Tags: php, exec, ghostscript

I've taken help from the following link:

> [Conversion PDF to PNG or JPEG is very very slow using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562471/conversion-pdf-to-png-or-jpeg-is-very-very-slow-using-imagemagick?rq=1)

Tried to convert a `.pdf` file to `.png` from the top answer given to the above question.

When I executed the following command from terminal, it worked.

```
gs -o /Users/dhiwatdg/Desktop/terror2.png -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dLastPage=1 -quality=200 -r72 /Users/dhiwatdg/Desktop/one.pdf
```

i.e., my first page of `one.pdf` was converted to `terror.png`

But when I tried to do the same using a php script, it was not working and following is my code:

```
exec("gs -o /Users/dhiwatdg/Desktop/terror2.png -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dLastPage=1 -quality=200 -r72 /Users/dhiwatdg/Desktop/one.pdf");
```

I think the server was not able to recognise `gs`. How do I sort this out?

Comment: Try using a full path to where `gs` is - `/usr/bin/local/gs`, or wherever the executable lives.

Comment: @andrewsi I tried looking for the path where gs is located, but I couldn't. Could you please let me know how do I find the path?

Comment: I think you'll be able to find it with `which gs`.

Comment: @andrewsi: Please convert your comment into an answer

Comment: @DhiwaTdG: Please upvote + accept andrewsi's answer (if he really does add it as recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following command to check which `gs` is used by typing this in the terminal:

```
which gs
```

This would give you the full path of the executable. In my Ubuntu:

```
$ which gs
/usr/bin/gs
```

Hope this helps.