# How to use crop from PDF to PNG tiles using ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

Good day,

I have large issue cropping the PDF to PNG

PDF is about 1,6MB (2500x2500) and one process takes about 7-10min and generates 700MB of temporary files.
e.g.

```
exec("convert -density 400 'file.pdf' -resize 150% -crop 48x24@ png32:'file_%d.png'");
```

One PDF must generate PNGs from size 25% to 200%

Here i generate attributes like density, size for resizing in % and grids row and column count

```
$x = 0; $y = 0;
for ($i = 25; $i <= 200; $i += 25) {
    $x += 8; $y += 4;

    $convert[$i] = ['density' => (($i < 75) ? 200 : ($i < 150) ? 300 : ($i < 200) ? 400 : 500), 'tiles' => implode("x", [$x, $y])];
}
```

After i launch converter one after one and it's extremely expensive in time.

```
$file_cropper = function($filename, $additional = '') use ($density, $size, $tiles) {
    $pid = exec("convert -density $density ".escapeshellarg($filename)." -resize $size% -crop $tiles@ ".$additional." png32:".escapeshellarg(str_replace(".pdf", "_%d.png", $filename))." >/dev/null & echo $!");
    do {
        /* some really fast code */
    } while (file_exists("/proc/{$pid}"));
};
```

If i launch it simultaneously (8 processes) then ImageMagick eats all the space i have (40GB) => ~35GB of temporary files

Where is my problem, what am i doing wrong?

i tried to pass params below to functions $additional var:

```
"-page 0x0+0+0"
"+repage"
"-page 0x0+0+0 +repage"
"+repage -page 0x0+0+0"
```

nothing changes

Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-06-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
2GB / 2CPU

**EDITED**

After a while managed to replace ImageMagick on GhostScript

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r240 -sOutputFile=\"file.png\" file.pdf` but can't understand how to scale image and crop it.

crop with ImageMagick generates ~35GB temporary files and takes more time than previously.

Comment: This question looks relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562471/conversion-pdf-to-png-or-jpeg-is-very-very-slow-using-imagemagick. You could do the conversion in two stages (1) produce an unscaled PNG as, using `gs`, as suggested in the answer (2) then rescale/crop that, using `convert` to produce each of the scaled PNGs.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday realized, that gs way faster and easier to make some first steps. Now searching the way to scale it and crop. Will look at question you provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem that way:

1. `$info = exec("identify -ping %w {$original_pdf_file}"); preg_match('/(\d+x\d+)/', $info, $matches);`
2. `"gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r{$r} -g{$dim} -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=\"{$png}\" {$filename}"`
3. `"convert ".escapeshellarg($png)." -gravity center -background none -extent {$ex}x{$ex} ".escapeshellarg($png)`
4. `"convert ".escapeshellarg($png)." -crop {$tiles}x{$tiles}! +repage ".escapeshellarg(str_replace(".png", "_%d.png", $png))`

where:

- $filename = file.pdf
- $png = file.png
- $r = 120
- $ex = 4000
- $dim = $matches[1]

Step:

1. gives me dimension of original file after what i can play with size of png in the future
2. converts pdf to png with size i need with aspect ratio
3. converts png to size i wish with aspect ratio 1:1
4. cropping everything

this process takes 27.59s on my machine with image resolution 4000x4000 and size of file - only 1,4MB & 0-30MB of temporary files.