# PDF 2 Image using PHP without loss of quality?

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagick

I'm trying to convert a pdf to an image file (png, jpg, gif does not matter).

But using the following code:

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('helloworld.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $im;
?>
```

Picture quality is degraded significantly.

Is there any way to convert it with no or very little quality loss ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP+Imagick - PNG Compression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462827/phpimagick-png-compression)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert multipage PDF to PNG and back (Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710118/convert-multipage-pdf-to-png-and-back-linux)

Answer (score -1):

you have to play with [Imagick::setCompression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompression.php), [Imagick::setCompressionQuality](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php) and [Imagick::setImageCompression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompression.php)

for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047269/1713660) guy helped

```
$im->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED); 
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(0);
```

anyway, you have to put some of this strings before you format the image to png

Comment: If you find the solution on a similar question on [so], instead of copying it, flag the questions as [duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/212576).

Comment: @hjpotter92 no, I didn't, it's just an example how someone else used these functions. Note, that answer I linked to was not a solution

Comment: @hjpotter92 also, note, that another answer in [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12054887/1713660) tred ([Convert multipage PDF to PNG and back (Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710118/convert-multipage-pdf-to-png-and-back-linux/12046542#12046542)) points to stackoverflow again but it wasn't downvoted, because it could be helpfull (just think about this)

Comment: Well, no change.
Here is a demo of what my code is producing:
http://goo.gl/wW8S2L

With the code:

    `<?php
    $im = new imagick('hello.pdf[0]');
    $im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED); 
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(5);
    $im->setImageFormat('png');
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo $im;
    ?>`

Original pdf:
http://goo.gl/l2C8tM