# Compress PNG files in PHP

Tags: php, c, compression, png, cairo

I am generating PNG file with cairo extension of PHP. The image contains a background and a text. Now I want to compress these images by PHP after its generated by cairo. Is there any library to do this?

I found *pngcrush* tool. But its a command line tool. I dont want to invoke `system` call. If there is not PHP solution a C solution would do. In that case I'll make a PHP extension.

I have read [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462827/phpimagick-png-compression) question. But there is no answer in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [PngOptimizer](http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer). You can get the source for it at the bottom of the page, and it has a separated CLI version too.

Only problem is that source is C++ , not ANSI C. I have never made a PHP extension, so i don't know if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [imagepng()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) ...

```
//If you don't already have a handle to the image and it's just on the file system...
$im = imagecreatefrompng("yourGenerateFile.png");
$quality = 5; //0 - 9 (0= no compression, 9 = high compression)
imagepng($im, 'file/to/save.png', $quality);  //leave out filename if you want it to output to the buffer
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: I have already a cairo handle but not a gd handle. I'll try your code and let you know.

Comment: The quality is not preserved. Transparency lost completely!

Comment: For transparency use :  `imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);` 
like said here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#43024

Answer (score 0):

For C code take a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).  It looks like there is a [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension too.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462827/phpimagick-png-compression it does not work that way.

Comment: Aha!  It looks like a PHP problem not an ImageMagick issue.  You could either add the flag to the PHP-ImageMagick extension or create your own.  [MagickCore](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) has an example (search for 'example') of how to convert a gif to a png in code.

Comment: If you see the related question, there OP tried it with PHP but I tried in command line too. in both case  I achieve no more than 10% compression.